# 1 picture of 4 not completely aligned

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, subcaption

New to LaTeX. I made a figure with 4 pictures in a 2x2 grid format, and one of the images is not aligned with the rest of them despite having the same code. To confirm it wasn't the images I tried swapping the other images in but the top right image is always canted to the right. It's not an earth shattering problem but is annoying, as my other graphics align perfectly with each other within the figure.

my code at the moment:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}        
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample A SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample A SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:A SEM}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}     
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample B SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample B SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:B SEM}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}   
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample C SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample C SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:C SEM}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}       
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample D SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample D SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:D SEM}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{comparison of SEM micrographs for all the samples}
\label{fig:SEMimages}
\end{figure}
```

for some reason image B (sample B sem micrograph) is squished to the right.

[image: ]]][1](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)

The images are all the same size so I'm not sure what is causing this. any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is the same as in a normal text paragraph: All lines with the exception of the last are justified to the margin and spaces between them stretch. Add an empty line between subfigure 2 + 3 to create two paragraphs.

Comment: As an alternative to Ulrike's excellent comment you can add `\raggedright` or `\centering` after `\begin{figure}` to not justify the content but set it either ragged right or centered line by line. Perhaps, you could also change `0.48\linewidth` to `.5\linewidth` and `\end{subfigure}` to `\end{subfigure}\linebreak[1]`. But I've not tested the last suggestion, because you've not added a minimal working example, but only a code snippet.

Comment: Or (third alternative) if you want the second row to also have the second `subfigure` pushed to the right margin add `\hfill` after the `\end{subfigure}` of the first of that row.

Answer (score 8):

As @UlrikeFischer has already suggested in a comment, the uneven-whitespace issue disappears if you insert a blank line after the second of four `subfigure` environments. However, this comes at the cost of there now being hardly any horizontal separation at all between the pairs of `subfigure` environments. The remedy? Insert a couple of `\hfill` directives. And, by all means, do insert a spacer directive such as `\bigskip` or `\medskip` before the second row of images, to clarify to which graphs the subcaptions (a) and (b) belong.

Incidentally, none of the four `\centering` directives are needed. I'd comment them out -- or just delete them.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}  % remove 'demo' option in real doc.

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}        
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample A SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample A SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:A SEM}
\end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- new
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}     
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample B SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample B SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:B SEM}
\end{subfigure} % new: next line is blank

\bigskip % <-- new
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}   
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample C SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample C SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:C SEM}
\end{subfigure}\hfill % <-- new
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}       
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Sample D SEM micrograph.png}
    \caption{sample D SEM micrograph}
    \label{fig:D SEM}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{comparison of SEM micrographs for all the samples}
\label{fig:SEMimages}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```